# Print Quality is poor when printing from Chrome / Firefox vs Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, printing, internet-explorer, zebra-printer

Trying to print on a thermal printer and I have noticed that the print quality is very poor when printing from any browser other than Internet explorer.

I'm concerned about the barcodes specifically as they appear has wavy lines (in chrome and firefox). However, when printed from Internet explorer, the print quality is clear and the barcode is crisp and scannable.

I've tried changing printer settings > Dithering to 'None'. However the difference is marginal

Printer Settings - Dithering:

[image: Printer Settings - Dithering]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having same issue. You can use Seagull drivers.

> Solution:
>   Use the Seagull Drivers and turn dithering off.
>   The seagull drivers are much easier and straightforward while having all of the printer options set-able.
>
> Configuration:
>   1: Download and Install the Seagull Driver Package:
>   http://www.seagullscientific.com/drivers/printer-driver-features?m=zebra+lp284411
>   2: Setup your custom paper stocks for easy selection in drop-down of print dialog
>   I Use 4 x 6 for shipping labels and 1.25 x 2.25 for FBA labels (Amazon also uses 1.25 x 2.25 labels in their warehouses)
>   3: Turn Dithering Off
>   4: Set Darkness to Max
>   5: Set Speed to 1.5" or lowest tollerable
>
> BAMMM! you can now print direct from the chrome print dialog by setting the following in the chorme dialog:
>   1: Select Paper Stock from your custom stock setup in the print driver
>   2: Turn margins off

Source: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/for-those-trying-to-setup-a-zebra-lp2844-and-are-getting-blurry-fuzzy-label/160034

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.

Comment: Sorry just realised I had to mark this as answer :)